# Separate string

Tags: javascript, string

I have complete addresses (street address, state, country) and want to separate it in

```
address.address
address.state
address.country
```

for example

```
var addressString = 'Calle del Padre Jesús Ordóñez, 18. 1, Madrid, España'
```

the outcome should be:

```
address.address: Calle del Padre Jesús Ordóñez, 18. 1,
address.state: Madrid
address.country: España
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the fields by using [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g9uvB7/1)). Then you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (or manually assign), the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th parts of the string to the variables, and create an object:

```js
const addressString = 'Calle del Padre Jesús Ordóñez, 18. 1, Madrid, España';

const [,addr, state, country] = addressString.match(/(.+),\s+([^,]+),\s+([^,]+)$/);

const address = {
  address: addr,
  state,
  country
};

console.log(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 offers us destructuring, template strings and porperty shortcuts, making this whole process almost trivial for addresses that use a consistent seperator.

```js
const address_string = 'Calle del Padre Jesús Ordóñez, 18. 1, Madrid, España';
const [ street, number, state, country ] = address_string.split( ',' );
const address = { "address" : `${street}, ${number}`, state, country };
console.dir( address );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your project, but it would be preferable to get the address already splitted, and join it when needed.

You could use split function to split your string at commas. If needed, you could join back the entire array in one string but without the two last index of the array, in order to get address, state, and country as needed (assuming state and country don't contain a comma).